# class server unexpected reserved word error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run ThingsBoard demo-tool.js sample and I repeatedly get an unexpected reserved word error.  I'm at a total loss as how to resolve this issue as my javascript experience/knowledge is very minimal. Node is at version v0.10.29 and NPM is at version 1.4.21. It appears as though class is the unexpected reserved word. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Public $ sudo node demo-tool.js

/home/pi/Public/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules/websocket-stream/server.js:6
class Server extends WebSocketServer{
^^^^^
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word

```
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Public/node_modules/mqtt/node_modules

/websocket-stream/index.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

pi@raspberrypi:~/Public $
```

Comment: [try updating your version of node](http://thisdavej.com/upgrading-to-more-recent-versions-of-node-js-on-the-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: Can you try upgrading your node.js !?

Comment: Rico,  I followed the instructions in your link and upgraded node to V8.9.0 and this solved my problem.  Thanks!!!!